# pandas.io.ga not working for me

Tags: pandas, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So I have worked through the [Hello Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) tutorial to confirm that OAuth2 is working as expected for me, but I'm not having any luck with the pandas.io.ga module. In particular, I am stuck with this error:

```
In [1]: from pandas.io import ga

In [2]: df = ga.read_ga("pageviews", "pagePath", "2014-07-08")
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py:1162: FutureWarning: using '-' to provide set differences 
with Indexes is deprecated, use .difference()
"use .difference()",FutureWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py:1147: FutureWarning: using '+' to provide set union with 
Indexes is deprecated, use '|' or .union()
"use '|' or .union()",FutureWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b5343faf9ae6> in <module>()
----> 1 df = ga.read_ga("pageviews", "pagePath", "2014-07-08")

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/ga.pyc in read_ga(metrics, dimensions, start_date, **kwargs)
    105     reader = GAnalytics(**reader_kwds)
    106     return reader.get_data(metrics=metrics, start_date=start_date,
--> 107                            dimensions=dimensions, **kwargs)
    108 
    109 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/ga.pyc in get_data(self, metrics, start_date, end_date, dimensions, 
segment, filters, start_index, max_results, index_col, parse_dates, keep_date_col, date_parser, na_values, converters, 
sort, dayfirst, account_name, account_id, property_name, property_id, profile_name, profile_id, chunksize)
    293 
    294         if chunksize is None:
--> 295             return _read(start_index, max_results)
    296 
    297         def iterator():

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/ga.pyc in _read(start, result_size)
    287                                         dayfirst=dayfirst,
    288                                         na_values=na_values,
--> 289                                         converters=converters, sort=sort)
    290             except HttpError as inst:
    291                 raise ValueError('Google API error %s: %s' % (inst.resp.status,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/ga.pyc in _parse_data(self, rows, col_info, index_col, parse_dates, 
keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, na_values, converters, sort)
    313                                   keep_date_col=keep_date_col,
    314                                   converters=converters,
--> 315                                   header=None, names=col_names))
    316 
    317         if isinstance(sort, bool) and sort:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    237 
    238     # Create the parser.
--> 239     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    240 
    241     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    551             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    552 
--> 553         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    554 
    555     def _get_options_with_defaults(self, engine):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _make_engine(self, engine)
    694             elif engine == 'python-fwf':
    695                 klass = FixedWidthFieldParser
--> 696             self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
    697 
    698     def _failover_to_python(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, **kwds)
   1412         if not self._has_complex_date_col:
   1413             (index_names,
-> 1414              self.orig_names, self.columns) = self._get_index_name(self.columns)
   1415             self._name_processed = True
   1416             if self.index_names is None:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _get_index_name(self, columns)
   1886             # Case 2
   1887             (index_name, columns_,
-> 1888              self.index_col) = _clean_index_names(columns, self.index_col)
   1889 
   1890         return index_name, orig_names, columns

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _clean_index_names(columns, index_col)
   2171                     break
   2172         else:
-> 2173             name = cp_cols[c]
   2174             columns.remove(name)
   2175             index_names.append(name)

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Index
```

OAuth2 is working as expected and I have only used these parameters as demo variables--the query itself is junk.  Basically, I cannot figure out where the error is coming from, and would appreciate any pointers that one may have.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION (SORT OF)**

Not sure if this has to do with the data I'm trying to access or what, but the offending Index type error I'm getting arises from the the index_col variable in pandas.io.ga.GDataReader.get_data() is of type pandas.core.index.Index.  This is fed to pandas.io.parsers._read() in _parse_data() which falls over. I don't understand this, but it is the breaking point for me.

As a fix--if anyone else is having this problem--I have edited line 270 of ga.py to:

```
index_col = _clean_index(list(dimensions), parse_dates).tolist()
```

and everything is now smooth as butter, but I suspect this may break things in other situations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this module isn't really documented and the errors aren't always meaningful. Include your `account_name`, `property_name` and `profile_name` (`profile_name` is the `View` in the online version). Then include some `dimensions` and `metrics` you are interested in. Also make sure that the `client_secrets.json` is in the `pandas.io` directory. An example:

```
ga.read_ga(account_name=account_name,
           property_name=property_name,
           profile_name=profile_name,
           dimensions=['date', 'hour', 'minute'],
           metrics=['pageviews'],
           start_date=start_date,
           end_date=end_date,
           index_col=0,
           parse_dates={'datetime': ['date', 'hour', 'minute']},
           date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d %H %M'),
           max_results=max_results)
```

Also have a look at my recent step by step [blog post](http://blog.zoomeranalytics.com/google-analytics/) about GA with pandas.

Comment: Ah, that's even better!  Simply passing the index_col= keyword makes things work just fine.  If I don't do that (ie, don't pass that argument as in my example code), the "solution" I put in my above edit works, and creates a DataFrame object with a multi-index with date as the top level.